# Google Drive Quickstart Python - Localhost didn't send any data

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I've been following this guide:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python

and did everything up to the

```
python quickstart.py
```

part. When I do that it opens up a new browser (oddly not my default browser but whatever) and I get the OAuth screen, but once I click "Allow" it gives me a "localhost didn't send any data" error. The shell has:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py:255: 
UserWarning: Cannot access /Users/timothy.tran/.credentials/drive-
python-quickstart.json: No such file or directory
  warnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))
0:297: execution error:
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It means it cannot access this file:

```
Cannot access /Users/timothy.tran/.credentials/drive-
python-quickstart.json
```

because:

```
No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

I just got this quickstart running a while ago. When you click the oauth link generated by python commandline and it opens a random browser, copy that link and paste it in the browser where your gmail account (which you're also using in your google dev console) is currently logged-in. Let me know if you're still stuck after this.

Also I don't think you need a localhost to run this. If anything, I'd used a python virtual environment.

Comment: Yes I tried that as well and it gives me the screen to OAuth, but after clicking "allow" it gives me that same error. The local host error is when I try it in chrome. When I try it in Safari it gives me the "safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding" message.

Comment: are you connected to the internet? i dont see how this is related to localhost

Comment: Yes I am connected to the internet. Not sure if this matters at all but I'm on my company's server, which may have some security measures in place?

Comment: lol that nust be the reason. i thoufht u were testing at home in your own network

Comment: Ahh gotcha - let me investigate a bit more. If there's still a problem I'll let you know!